# Some Questions about Hartshorne Exercise II.1.8.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The exercise I want to ask is Hartsorne II 1.8.

> For any open subset $U \subset X$, show that the functor
> $\Gamma(U,\cdot)$ from sheaves on $X$ to abelian groups is a left
> exact functor, i.e if $0 \to \mathcal{F'} \to  \mathcal{F} \to 
>  \mathcal{F''}  $ is a en exact sequences of sheaves, then $0 \to
>  \Gamma(U,\mathcal{F'}) \to   \Gamma(U,\mathcal{F}) \to  
>  \Gamma(U,\mathcal{F''})  $ is an exact sequence of groups.

claim is clearly , i) $\Gamma(U,\mathcal{F'}) \to   \Gamma(U,\mathcal{F}) $ is injective and ii) $Im[\Gamma(U,\mathcal{F}) \to \Gamma(U,\mathcal{F''})]=Ker [\Gamma(U,\mathcal{F'}) \to \Gamma(U,\mathcal{F})] $ . My question is whether or not my thought of i) is right way. For convenience, I put $\varphi :\mathcal{F'} \to  \mathcal{F}, \overset{\sim}\varphi :\Gamma(U,\mathcal{F'}) \to  \Gamma(U,\mathcal{F}) $  . Then, **claim** : $Ker \overset{\sim}{\varphi}(~= \left \{ f \in \Gamma(U,\mathcal{F})~ | ~ \overset{\sim}{\varphi}(f)=0\right \}~)=  \left \{  0=f\right \}$ . To check the claim, I'll use the assumption : $ Ker \varphi = \left \{ [0]  \right \} $ (This part is unsure, though, I heard an exact seq of sheaves is exact sequence iff stalk at each point $x$ is exact sequence. Thus, I think that it is right to pick an equivalence class $[0]$.) Anyway, if $g \in [0]$ then $g\sim {0}$, i.e there exists an open set $x \in V \subset U \cap U'$ such that $ ~ g|_{V}= 0|_V = 0$.  However, since this happens whenever we choose **every point** $x \in X$, this holds globally, i.e $Ker \varphi = \left \{  0=f\right \} $. Is it right idea?

Comment: Yes, that seems correct.